# 1 class_names = dataset.class_names 2 class_names "NameError: name 'dataset' is not defined "

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from  tensorflow.keras import models, layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IMAGE_SIZE = 256
BATCH_SIZE = 32

dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "Plantvillage",
    shuffle= True,
    image_size = (IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)

class_names = dataset.class_names
class_names
```

I'm getting error:

```
1 class_names = dataset.class_names 2 class_names "NameError: name 'dataset' is not defined "
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full error message

Comment: Also are you sure that this is the exact code that is generating the error? Perhaps you have a typo?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ClaudiaR Is it now clear ? yes, it is the exact code

Comment: Are you perhaps working on a Google Colab notebook, or with a regular `.py` file on your computer? Do you have a `Plantvillage` folder inside the directory where you're executing the code from?

Comment: I'm using jupyter notebook . Yes it is inside the folder

Comment: If you add a print(dataset) after dataset creation, what do you get?

Comment: It's showing "SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call "

Comment: Is this the only code you are executing? Do you have other imports or other code executed before the one you posted? I suspect that there is something going on with the name of your variable `dataset`, maybe a shadowing of a method. Instead of calling it `dataset`, try renaming it in `my_dataset`

Comment: Yes this the only code I'm executing. I'm using this first time. I tried renaming with but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the complete path to this specifc folder(Plantvillage) inside `image_dataset_from_directory` to access the dataset where all the images are residing into different folders as per its class_names.

**For example:** Suppose I have a Cat and a Dog two folders inside the "Data\dataset" folder and each folder has 20 cats images and 20 dogs images then you can access both folders by specifying the root path as below:

```
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "D:\Data\Dataset",  # This will show the inside folder names along with each folder images count
    shuffle= True,
    image_size = (IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)

class_names = dataset.class_names
class_names
```

Output:

```
        Found 40 files belonging to 2 classes.
Out[3]: ['Cat', 'Dog']
```